# Add a counter in tkinter flash card

Tags: tkinter, counter

I have a python script running a flash card game. It is very simple. What I am trying to do is to add also a gui label with a counter that updates the missing card every time I click the NEXT button. In the example code I have only 3 flash cards, and the format I would like is "3/3", "1/3", "0/3".

Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from random import shuffle

root = Tk()
root.title('Domande')
root.geometry("700x700")

words = [
    (("Roma"), ("Stadio Olimpico")),
    (("Milan"), ("Stadio San Siro")),
    (("Genoa"), ("Stadio Marassi"))
]

shuffle(words)

# get a count of our wods list
count = len(words)


random_domande = 0


def increment(x):
    global random_domande
    random_domande = random_domande+x


def loadword():
    global hinter, hint_count

    # Clear screen
    answer_label.config(text="")
    label.config(text="")
    # my_entry.delete(0, END)
    hint_label.config(text="")
    # Reset Hint stuff
    hinter = ""
    hint_count = 0
    domande.config(text=words[random_domande][0])


def next():
    increment(1)
    loadword()
    prev_button["state"] = "active"

    if random_domande == count - 1:
        next_button["state"] = "disabled"


def prev():
    increment(-1)
    loadword()
    next_button["state"] = "active"

    if random_domande == 0:
        prev_button["state"] = "disabled"

hinter = ""
hint_count = 0


def hint():
    global hint_count
    global hinter

    if hint_count < len(words[random_domande][1]):
        hinter = hinter + words[random_domande][1][hint_count]
        hint_label.config(text=hinter)
        hint_count += 1

# Define function to hide the widget

def hide_widget(widget):
    widget.pack_forget()
    widget.config(text=words[random_domande][1])

# Define a function to show the widget


def show_widget(widget):
    widget.pack()
    widget.config(text=words[random_domande][1])


# Labels
domande = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 14))
domande.pack(pady=50)

answer_label = Label(root, text="")
answer_label.pack(pady=20)

# Create an Label Widget
label = Label(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 14))
label.pack(pady=20)

# Create a button Widget
button_hide = Button(root, text="Hide", command=lambda: hide_widget(label))
button_hide.pack(pady=20)

button_show = Button(root, text="Show", command=lambda: show_widget(label))
button_show.pack()

# Create Buttons
button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(pady=20)

prev_button = Button(button_frame, text="Prev", command=prev, state="disabled")
prev_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

next_button = Button(button_frame, text="Next", command=next)
next_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

hint_button = Button(button_frame, text="Hint", command=hint)
hint_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20)

# Create Hint Label
hint_label = Label(root, text="")
hint_label.pack(pady=20)

# Run next function when the program starts
loadword()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "label with a counter that updates the missing card"? Am I correct in understanding that when the window is opened, the text in the label should be "1/3"? When you click the Next button, the text changes to "2/3", "3/3", etc. Clicking the Prev button displays the previous numbers.

Comment: I would start from the total amount of flash card when the window is open, counting, by pressing the Next button, the missing ones.